# Incorrect identification of Visual Studio warning CA1806 (Do not ignore method results) when using FluentAssertion

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, fluent-assertions

I'm writing a C# unit test in Visual Studio 2019. I'm using Xunit with FluentAssertion.

The two main lines of code (for illustrative purposes) in one of the tests are:

```
Action a = () => new SomeClass(null);
a.Should().Throw<ArgumentNullException>();
```

However, this causes a compiler CA1806 Warning:
"Ctor_WhenInvalidArgs_ThenThrowException creates a new instance of SomeClass which is never used. Pass the instance as an argument to another method, assign the instance to a variable, or remove the object creation if it is unnecessary."

How can I resolve the warning while still using FluentAssertion to ensure that the constructor throws the correct exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a new instance of class `SomeClass` you finally create a function, the constructor "returns" a new instance. But, you assigning it to an action, so the "result" is ignored.

Use `Func<T>` instead and CS1806 is gone.

```cs
Func<SomeClass> f = () => new SomeClass(null);
f.Should().Throw<ArgumentNullException>();
```